# remove carriage return in sqr

Tags: report, sqr

I have a text column that may or may not contain carriage returns. When they do contain them, it throws off my report and adds an extra line. Is there a way to remove carriage returns and replace them with a space?

Answer (score 0):

In the SQR script just modify the initial select from the database. I used the str_replace() function to remove any carriage returns and line feeds from that text field.

eg.

SELECT str_replace(COMMENT_TXT, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), "")
FROM TABLE_NAME

char(13) and char(10) represent carriage return and line feed respectively.